# reading Csv as custom data types

Tags: csv, haskell

I have a csv at some `filePath` with two columns with no headers

```
john,304
sarah,300
...
```

I have been able to read the csv as such:

```
import Data.Csv as Csv
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Vector as V

...
results <- fmap V.toList . Csv.decode @(String,Integer) Csv.NoHeader <$> BL.readFile filePath
-- Right [("john",300),("sarah",302)]
```

If I have custom data type for the csv columns as such:

```
data PersonnelData = PersonnelData
{ name :: !String
, amount :: !Integer
} deriving (Show, Generic, Csv.FromRecord)
```

How can I modify the above to decode / read the file for this data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have this:

```
Csv.decode @(String,Integer)
```

You are are using a [visible type application](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html) to *explicitly* tell `Csv.decode` that its first type parameter should be the type `(String, Integer)`. Let's have a look at [the signature for `decode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.5.3.0/docs/Data-Csv.html#v:decode) to see what that means:

```
decode :: FromRecord a   
       => HasHeader 
       -> ByteString    
       -> Either String (Vector a)
```

There's only one type parameter, and it's pretty clear from where it appears (in the output) that it is the type that `decode` is decoding into. So `Csv.decode @(String,Integer)` is a function that *explicitly* decodes CSV records to `(String, Integer)`.

So the only change you need to make to your code is to explicitly tell it you want to decode to `PersonnelData` instead of `(String, Integer)`. Just use `Csv.decode @PersonnelData`. (You need a `FromRecord` instance, but you already have provided that by `deriving` it)